# Practical usage of noSQL

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database, nosql

I’m starting a new web project and have to decide what database to use. I know, the question is very long but please bear with me on this.

I am very familiar with relational databases and have used frameworks like hibernate to get my data from the DB into Objects. But I have no experience with noSQL DBs. I am aware of the concepts of Document, Key-Value, etc. types.
While I do my research one question pops out every time and I don’t know how someone would handle this in noSQL DBs like MongoDB or any other Document-Typed noSQL DB where consistency takes top priority.

**For example**: let’s assume that we are creating a small shopping management system where customers can buy and sell stuff.
We have:

- CUSTOMERs
- ORDERs
- PRODUCTs

A single CUSTOMER can have multiple ORDERs and an ORDER can have multiple PRODUCTs.

In a traditional RDBMS I would of course have 3 tables.
In the first version of our application, the front end for the customer should display his/her personal data, ORDERs and all the PRODUCTs he or she bought per order. Also which products are available for sale. So I guess in noSQL I would model the CUSTOMER class like this:

```
{
    "id": 993784,
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "orders": [
        {
            "id": 3234,
            "quantity": 4,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id:" 378234,
                    "type": "TV",
                    "resolution": "1920x1080",
                    "screenSize":37,
                    "price": 999
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "products": [
        {
            "id:" 7932,
            "type": "car",
            "sold": false,
            "horsepower": 90
        }
    ]
}
```

But later I want to extend my application to have 3 different UIs instead of only the first one:

- The CUSTOMER Dashboard where a customer can view all his/her orders.
- The PRODUCT Dashboard where a customer can add or remove products in his/her store.
- THE SOLD Dashboard where a customer can view all sold PRODUCTs ready for shipping.

One very important thing to consider (the reason why I even bother asking this question): I want to be flexible with the classes like PRODUCT because products can have different properties. For Example: A TV has screen size and resolution while a car has horsepower and other properties. And if a user adds a new product, he or she should be able to dynamically add those properties depending on what he/she knows about it.

---

**Now to some practical use cases of two fictional users Jane and John:**

Let's say, Jane buys from John. Does that mean i have to create the PRODUCTs two times? One time as a child of Jane's ORDER and another time to stay in the "products" property of John?

Later Jane wants to view all products that are available from any user. Do i have to load every user to query the "products" property to generate a list of all products?

In version 2 of the application i want to enable John to view all outgoing orders (not orders he made but orders from other users who bought stuff from him) instead of viewing all sold products. How would this be done in noSQL? Would i now need to create an "outgoing" array of orders and duplicate them? (an outgoing order of Jane is an incoming order of John)

Some of you may say that noSQL is not right for this use case but isn’t that very common? Especially when we do not know what the future brings? If it does not fit for this use case, what use case would it fit into? Only baby applications (I guess not)? Wasn’t noSQL designed for more complex and flexible data?

Thank you very much for your advises and opinions!

### EDIT 1:

Because this question was put on hold because of the unprecise question:
I made a very clear and simple example. So my question is not general about the use of noSQL but how to handle this specific example. How would a experienced noSQL user handle this use case? How to model this data? A recommendation to simply not use noSQL at all for this use case is also a valid answer to me.

I simply want to know how to use a noSQL database but still be able to manage entities and avoid redundancy. 
For example: Are MongoDB's DBRefs/Manual refs a good way to achieve this? Performance issues because of multiple queries? What else to think about? I guess these questions can probably be answered quite well.

Comment: At those who want this closed because they consider this "primarily opinion-based": I think mesx is asking very clear questions which have nothing to do with one's opinion on NoSQL, but about its concept. I consider this question very well written and I'm also interested in the answers of some experienced NoSQL people on this.

Answer (score 3):

There probably isn't the one right answer to your question. But I'll make a start.

While it is technically possible in NoSQL to store some business entity together with all entities that are transitively linked with it (like Customer, Order, Product), it is't always clever to do so. The traditional reasons for separating entities, namely redundancies and therefore update and delete anomalies, don't just go away because a different platform is used.

So if you stored the product description with every customer who buys or sells this product, you will get update anomalies. If you have to change the screen size from 37 to 35, you'll have to find all customer records containing this product, which can be quite cumbersome.

Also, building up such a deep nested structure favors one direction of evaluating those structures over all other directions. If you put all orders and products into the customer document, this is very fine for getting a comprehensive view for a customer: whatever she bought throughout her lifetime. But if you want to query your database by orders (which orders need to be fulfilled tonight?) or products (who ordered product 1234?) you'll have to load tons of data that are of no interest to this query.

Similar questions are due to storing *all* orders with a customer. Old orders will sometimes still be of interest, so they may not be deleted. But do you want to load lots of orders *everytime* you load the customer?

This doesn't mean not to make use of the complex structuring made possible by a document store. As a **rule of thumb**, I would suggest: As long as the nested information belongs to the same business entity, put it into one document. If, e.g., the product description has some hierarchic structure, like nested sections consisting of text, pics, and videos, they may all go into one document. But entities with a totally different life cycle, like customers, orders, and suppliers, should be kept separate. Another indicator is references: A product will frequently be referenced as a whole, e.g. when it is ordered by a customer or ordered from a supplier. But the different parts of the product description may possibly never be referenced from the outside.

This rule of thumb wasn't completely precise, and it's not supposed to be. One person's business entity is another person's dumb attribute. Imagine the color of a car: For the car owner, it's just a piece of information describing a car. For the manufacturer, it's a business entity, having an availability, a price, one or more suppliers, a way of handling it, etc.

Your question also touches the aspect of dynamically adding attributes. This is often praised as one of the goodies of NoSQL, but it's no free lunch. Let's assume, as you mentioned, that *the user* may add attributes. That's technically possible, but how will these attributes be processed by the system? There won't be a specific view, nor specific business rules, for those attributes. So the best the system can do is offer some generic mechanism for displaying those attributes that were defined at runtime and never reflected in the program code.

This doesn't mean the feature is useless. Imagine your product description may be complex, as described above. You might build a generic mechanism to display (and edit) descriptions made up of sections, texts, images, etc., and afterwards the users may enter descriptions of unlimited width and depth. But in contrast, imagine your user will add a tiny `delivery date` attribute to the order. Unless the system knows specifically how to interpret this date, it will just be a dumb piece of information without any effect.

Now imagine not the user, but *the developer* adds new attributes. She has the opportunity to enhance the code at the same time, e.g. building some functionality around delivery dates. But this means that, although the database doesn't require it by its own, a new release of the software needs to be rolled out to make use of the new information.

The absence of a database scheme even makes the programmer's task more complicated. When a relational table has a certain column, you may be sure that each of its records has this column. If you want to make sure that it has a meaningful value, make it `not null`, and you may be sure that each record contains a value of the correct data type. Nothing like that is guaranteed by schemaless databases. So, when reading a record, defensive programming is needed to find out which parts are present, and whether they have the expected content. The same holds for database maintenance via administrative tools. Adding an attribute and initializing it with a default value is a 2-liner in SQL, or a couple of mouse clicks in pgadmin. For a schemaless database, you will write a short program on your own to achieve this.

This doesn't mean that I dislike NoSQL databases. But I think the "schemaless" characteristic is sometimes overestimated, and I wouldn't make it the main, or only, reason to employ such a database.